# python - slowness when running executable compare to running from my IDE (VS)

Tags: python

I developed small application and i run it through Visual Studio Code without issue.
I used PyInstaller in order to compile it as exe file and to send other to use.

The feedback i got is that it is relative running slow.
I want to emphasize that when i run it it runs fast.
Also the application parse data from web-sites (i.e. it needs to run when you are online). As far as i know they do not have any network issues that might effect the performance.

Can anyone suggest a reason why it runs slower to them?

Thanks in advance,
Asaf

Comment: Did you compare both versions side-by-side to see this behavior for yourself? Otherwise, you're chasing something very vague (someone else's perceived "slowness" compared to your perceived "not slowness"). Without some hard example, it's going to be difficult to offer much help (unless you get lucky and this is a known issue, which seems unlikely to me).

Comment: You are right it is hard as i dont see how they interact with the application. I have used the same exe in my computer and it seems to be working fine. I was thinking more towards maybe there are flags in PyInstaller that i should have used or not... or ...

Comment: ok. i'll check it F2F